# Why we can backup postgresql database backup without password?

Tags: postgresql

I want to backup my PostgreSQL database with `pg_dump` command that takes a lot of parameters.
One of them is `--no-password`.

Why this parameter is provided?

I mean if anyone can backup database, so what about security?

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) on this: "If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail." This parameter doesn't mean that you can connect (and dump) without knowing password, it is just help for (backup) scripts where entering passwords isn't possible by hand.

Comment: So how can I give this password at first command. I mean if I force password, after executing command it will prompt to give password. this don't work in some of application and they want whole command at one time

Comment: read docu please - link in my answer is good starting point. it describe how to provide password for scripts. postgresql has one from the most famous docu i have read ever.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dump the database without a password if you're not allowed to. Check your pg_hba.conf configuration.